# How to use Regex to split data together with extracting pattern value

Tags: c#, regex

I have to process text file like that:

```
 2010-04-02
 ...
 ...
 ...
 2010-05-01
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

It is possible to get values by using Split function:

```
Regex.Split(text, @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
```

Is there way to get dates and related text below the date?

My output should be array of items (date, text).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx), wrapping the string you're splitting on in () (making it a capture group) will result in these captures being included in the array.

`Regex.Split(text, @"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})")`

Answer (score 1):

Consider, instead, `DateTime.Parse()` and `DateTime.ParseExact()`. They're very efficient.

There's good reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

If you must use regular expressions, take a look at [this](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexsyntaxadvanced.aspx). There are options for matching patterns in multi-line text.